# How to disable Windows built-in keyboard using command

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, keyboard, terminal

Is there a way i can disable the Windows built-in keyboard via `Terminal Preview`, Just like how i can accomplish the same thing on Ubuntu with thee command `xinput disable <key>` ?

Comment: Unfortunately, Windows does not have a built-in command to disable a keyboard in the same way that Ubuntu's xinput command does.
You can use Device Manager to disable the built-in keyboard, or you can use third-party software to disable it.
You can also use the command prompt or powershell to disable it by disabling the device driver of the keyboard.
You can do this by running the command: "devcon.exe disable *PNP0303" (assuming the device ID of your built-in keyboard is PNP0303). But this may not work for all devices.